Modeling Condition Specific Associations
I am trying to model a crossover repeated measures design in which individuals complete both the active and control conditions. These individuals also complete cognitive testing before and after both conditions (for a total of four times). I want to examine the associations between the changes in a variable during the active and control conditions (e.g., HR during active and HR during control) with before and after cognitive changes. To model this, I utilized a linear mixed model with condition as a fixed effect and the interaction between HR and condition on cognitive changes (post-pre). Logically, it seems to make sense to account for the repeated measures but I have yet to see any publications that utilize this method. Could anyone provide some insight and/or share publications that have used this method?

Please edit the question to clarify what you mean by "I want to examine the associations between the changes in a variable during the active and control conditions (e.g., HR during active and HR during control) with before and after cognitive changes." Are you using a start-to-finish change in HR during each condition as a predictor, or some other HR value? What's the scale of your outcome, the cognitive test: is it essentially continuous, or a scale with a limited number of values? Comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted, so please edit the question to address those matters.
